# Highcharts Pie Chart.How to set labels in two lines

Tags: charts, highcharts, jsfiddle, pie-chart

I'm creating a pie chart in highcharts.

Does anybody know how to set data labels in two lines?

I'm finding this problem when the data labels are too long.

http://jsfiddle.net/larrytron/fSjnD/

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    maxStaggerLines:1,                    
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'                   

                },
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox jandler glander gramenauer gramen',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply set width for dataLabels, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/fSjnD/1/

```
style: {
    width: '100px'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply insert 
 in the data labels:

```
 data: [
      ['Firefox jandler glander <br><b>gramenauer gramen</b>',   45.0],
```

Note, for some reason, the second line loses the bold formatting unless you addit back in using  tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMLSW/

Comment: yes, you're right. But I need to do it dinamically, and I don't know how long are the labels, therefore I hoped there was some property able to do this automatically.