# How to set width limitation for text in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am using a pie chart for my diagram. The problems is sometimes the text or the name of a category is really long and it makes my pie chart gets smaller than usual.
How I can set a width limitation for each text?

This is my pie chart with a long category name:
 [Here](http://s12.postimg.org/99ossj8u5/Screen_Shot_2015_04_23_at_9_30_05_PM.png)

Comment: Do you wish to make it narrower by removing letters, or by shrinking the text? Or, I suppose, by wrapping it?

Comment: Yeah. By wrapping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329478/highcharts-pie-chart-how-to-set-labels-in-two-lines), and [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jxjf9rc/) that demonstrates.

In brief - you can add a style to the dataLabels:

```
style: {
    width: '50px'
}
```